# Problem with setbuf not working in multi-process

Tags: c, linux, buffering, multiprocess

As in the following code, 
I create a child process using fork function, remove the buffer of stdout, and create a race condition environment, 
but the two processes do not compete.

System: Linux user1-ubuntu64 4.18.0-20-generic
Compiler: gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)
Compile command: gcc -o test test.c

If give the parent process a very small delay(250ns), It work that I want.

The source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static void printatime(char *);

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printatime("AAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
    else
    {
        printatime("BBBBBBBBBBBB");
    }
    return 0;
}

static void printatime(char *str)
{
    char *ptr = str;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    while (*ptr)
    {
        putc(*ptr++, stdout);
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
user@ubuntu64:~/C$ BAABBABABAABBAAABBABABAB
```

Actual results:

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBuser@ubuntu64:~/C$ AAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: You have no control over the process scheduling, the OS can run your processes in any order it likes and preempt them whenever it wants. It seems that the kernel decided to run one of your processes to its exit before it ran the other. Try using much larger strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. Why does the string "user@ubuntu64" go between output strings? Is this a worthless question?

Comment: `the OS can run your processes in any order it likes` - first or your processes printf `BBBBBBBBB` then shell process printfs `user@ubuntu64:~/C$` then the second of your processes printfs `AAAAAAAAAAAA`. "in any order"

Comment: @KamilCuk
Is it right for cpu to run very small tasks in a series of work units for efficient processing?

Comment: ? I don't understand. CPU has nothing to do with it (well, it has, but CPU doesn't make decisions). It is right for operating system to schedule the execution of any program in any order it wants. You may have set `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`, but that doesn't mean that the shell will flush the output of your program at any time, between the strings. As said, try it with very, very, very long strings, todays CPUs are very fast, printing some `AAAAAAA` is very fast.

Comment: If you don't want the possibility of the shell prompt being interposed in the middle of the output, then have the parent `wait()` for the child before terminating.

Comment: btw, you should not call putc after fork (there is list of functions that could be called between fork and exec). from POSIX point its UB case.